# Phone back from repair, do I have to manually add all accounts?

Tags: 8.1, sync, backup, nokia-lumia-1020, reset

My Lumia 1020 was sent for repair and obviously was wiped first. I took a backup and when I plugged it back in was asked if I wanted to restore that backup - I said yes.

But other than my contacts being restored from my live.com account - which is hardly a backup, that's just live.com sync - nothing else is copied. My apps are downloading but my theme and email accounts are not kept at all, FaceBook integration, or WiFi networks, etc.

Is this normal? I rather thought the point of all this PC/cloud sync was my new phone would just work after a few minutes to sync everything?

Answer (score 2):

Well your backup should include things like your Homescreen layout, accent color and also some of your app data, if you have backup to the cloud enabled. However, this depends on how whether the developer intended for the data to be backuped. My email accounts were restored as well, I just had to enter my passwords, as are my Wifi connections.
The facebook connection will only work after you installed the app as its not included in the OS anymore.

Ultimately, this is not a complete backup where your phone gets copied to the cloud bit by bit.

Details about how to enable backup to the cloud can be found on [this help page](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/back-up-my-stuff).

Comment: I didn't get anything like that. Looks like I didn't have cloud backup turned on - is that the only way such things are remembered, not through the Windows Phone desktop application?

Comment: Unfortunately these things will only be stored in the cloud, yes.